# Русское написание названий английской улицы и театра

Tags: ономастика, прописная-строчная, пунктуация, топонимика

Как написать по-русски название лондонской улицы **Charing Cross Road**? Где ставить заглавные буквы, нужен ли дефис?
Следует ли название театра **Ковент-Гарден** брать в кавычки?

Answer (score 3):

Чаринг-Кросс роуд и Чаринг Кросс роуд (без дефиса) Название театра следует брать в кавычки в сочетание с родовым словом, т.к. нет синтаксической связи, название синтаксически не сочетается с родовым словом.

Подробнее о кавычках в названиях см. здесь:[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)

### Дополнение

По мнению Граммы.ру название театра Ковент Гарден следует писать без кавычек.

Ответ Граммы.ру

**Название театра Ковент-Гарден в соответствии с рекомендацией орфографических словарей пишется без кавычек.**

Comment: К сожалению ваша ссылка не работает. А мне вот кажется, что к слову роуд следует добавлять дефис. Ведь Бейкер-стрит пишется именно так.

Comment: А, вот нашел статью - http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2 - Здесь говорится наоборот: "условные наименования, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым словом. Они заключаются в кавычки" Выходит кавычки нужны

Comment: Это как раз та ссылка, которую привел я. Почему-то у меня не получилось, но я исправил.

Comment: Конечно, нужны. Я же написал в своем ответе, что кавычки нужны. Кавычки не нужны, если нет родового слова. Как в том примере, который привели Вы в комментариях.

Comment: Бейкрит -стрит составное название. А в вашем примере составное название "Чаринг-Кросс", а роуд в название не входит. Роуд - дорога. Поэтому тире перед  "роуд "не ставится.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать: со словом театр кавычки нужны, а без - нет? Но я так понимаю - Ковент-Гарден является условным названием, а не составным. А значит: "В отличие от них условные названия заключаются в кавычки как при наличии родового слова, так и при его отсутствии"

Comment: По поводу дефиса. Как мне кажется слово "роуд" такое же служебное слово как и "стрит", "авеню", "сквер", "парк", "террас" ну и другие, к сожалению всех не знаю. А они во всех примерах, что мне приходилось видеть пишутся через дефис.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что улицу следует писать так: улица Чаринг Кросс Роуд. Сначала поясню отсутствие дефиса. Дефис отсутствует ибо и в России тоже никто дефис не ставит, когда называют свои улицы двумя и более словами, если конечно грамматически слова пишутся без дефиса. И британцы тоже не ставят дефис в название этой улицы, да и другие языки тоже не имеют такой привычки раздифисывать ни свои, ни туземные улицы, если такого нет в оригинале.
Теперь что касается всех заглавных букв.
**Коротко.**
Все пишется заглавными буквами, как и в оригинале, и слово Road является частью имени улицы, а не просто обозначением, что это дорога.

**Детально.**
Т.к. Charing (Чаринг) - это название деревни, и тем самым заслуживает заглавную букву, то понятно что слово является частью имени улицы. Далее Cross; впринципе - это пересечение или крест, но в данном случае это уже не простое существительное, а стало частью имени собственного, как например слово земля, то что у нас под ногами и куда сажают растения и планета Земля (заглавная буква обязательна). К тому же есть такой перекресток в Лондоне, как Charing Cross и он также пишется заглавными буквами и обознаечается как junction (перекресток). Слово Road тоже является частью имени, пускай и когда-то могло просто обозначать дорогу, чтобы не путать с перекрестком Charing Cross, но и сами британцы расценивают это как часть имени, что очевидно из этой ([Charing Cross Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charing_Cross_Road)) статьи на Вики, цитирую *"Charing Cross Road **is a street** in central London..."*.

Ну а про Covent Garden (Ковент-Гарден), вы можете, либо последовать коннотации и написать это транслитерацией и через дефис, как собственно и статья на Вики ([Ковент-Гарден](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD_(%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD))), либо перевести на Русский (Монастырский Сад), как это делают и в других языках (не всмысле данного сада, а вообще). Никто же не говорит Krasnaya Ploshad или Zimniy Dvorets, но Red Square и Winter Palace. Ну а если конкретно театр, который ([Royal Opera House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Opera_House)), либо оставляйте Ковент-Гарден, либо Королевский Дом Оперы.

P.s. Если кому интересно и кто будет проверять, слово *сovent* является Англо-Французским, образованым от *convent* (монастырь) (которое французы записывают как *couvent*). Согласно статье на Вики [Covent Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covent_Garden).

P.s.s. Оперный театр Королевский в Монастырском Cаду. ;)

Answer (score 0):

По поводу закавычивания. На мой взгляд, здесь кавычки (кстати, ставить нужно кавычки-«ёлочки», согласно правилам типографики), потому что здесь название театра написано кириллицей.

Например: я посетил театр «Ковент-Гарден».

Comment: Интересно, что нашел в рассказе о Шерлоке Холмсе "Алое кольцо" упоминание театра "Ковент-Гарден" и там без кавычек. Последний абзац рассказа: http://www.conan-doyle.narod.ru/hlb/redcr.ru.txt . Трудно когда вокруг множество вариантов написания и даже на переводы художественной литературы нельзя положиться.

Comment: Быть может, это связано со стилем? Я же чётко сказал, что это название написано кириллицей, а это может означать, что правила русской пунктуации регламентируют такие случая.

Comment: А может, здесь другой фактор сыграл: корректор не заморачивался.

Comment: В рассказе все верно, прочитайте мой ответ внимательнее.